# Generating Multiple Pages of the Same Layout with Different Variables in Jekyll

Tags: html, jekyll

I'm using Jekyll to generate some static html pages. However I'd like to also generate the same layouts but with different variables. I for the life of me can't seem to articulate what I mean, so here's a basic example:

*_config.yml*

```
title: Foos and Bars
```

Generated *index.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Foos and Bars</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

And then I'd like to use the same base template (*index.html*) to generate more pages:

Generated *index_2.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Bars and Foos</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Generated *index_3.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>And Foos Bars</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Do I need to create another *_config.yml* file and run it each time? It just seems too inefficient. Can all of these variables be stored in the same *_config.yml*? Is there a program/method that's much more efficient?

Let me know what and if I can clarify. Thanks for taking a look and any input you might offer.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your problem, your solution would be to use a YAML front matter in each of your pages where the dedicated "`_config.yml` variables" are declared.

Given you have a layout file `page.html` in the `_layouts` directory of your jekyll project like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>{{ page.title }}</h1>
    <p>{{ page.content }}</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can then create a page -- let's call it `index.html` -- using this layout as follows:

```
---
layout: page
title: Foos and Bars
---
This is the text of my page
```

This will generate the following `index.html` in your `_site` directory:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Foos and Bars</h1>
    <p>This is the text of my page</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

This other page -- let's call it `index_2.html`:

```
---
layout: page
title: Bars and Foos
---
This is the other text of my other page
```

will generate `index_2.html` in your `_site` directory:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Bars and Foos</h1>
    <p>This is the other text of my other page</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

See [official documentation](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/frontmatter/).